# E2EE encryption workflow

Tags: encryption, signature

I need to send sensitive information from frontend to backend and from backend to frontend. Which is best to do this by encrypting all the communication between the parts? Should I use symmetric/asymmetric in encryption? What is the best approach?

Comment: TLS1.3 provides end-to-end encrypted channels between the parties that run it. Additionally, it supports mutual authentication and has some good implementions. A solid alternative is the noise protocol framework

Comment: A simple rule of thumb for performance: Asymmetric is for key exchange, Symmetric is for Encryption/Decryption.